# Run a .NET 6 project with .NET 8 SDK installed

Tags: c#, .net, linux

I have a .NET 6 project, and running it with .NET 6 SDK obviously works fine.

Running it having installed both .NET 6 and .NET 8 SDK builds correctly, but at runtime, I get the following error:

```
dotnet run
```

> [...]
> Unhandled exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): An error  occurred trying to start process  '/home/dpd-/prj/Test/bin/Debug/net6.0/Test'
> with working directory  '/home/dpd-/prj/Test'. No such file or  directory
>
> at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(ProcessStartInfo  startInfo, String resolvedFilename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String  cwd, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[]  groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd,  Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec)
> at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
> at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.Command.Execute(Action`1  processStarted)
> at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Run.RunCommand.Execute()
> at  System.CommandLine.Invocation.InvocationPipeline.Invoke(ParseResult  parseResult)
> at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, TimeSpan  startupTime, ITelemetry telemetryClient)

Running a .NET 8 project with both SDKs installed works fine.

A way to force using the .NET 6 SDK is to write into `global.json` (note `major` and not `latestMajor`):

```json
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "6.0.0",
    "rollForward": "major"
  }
}
```

But I cannot do this in shared projects and moreover this prevents:

- having mixed SDK projects in the same solution
- use C# 12 in .NET 6 projects

---

```
dotnet sdk check

.NET SDKs:
Version      Status                     
----------------------------------------
6.0.417      Patch 6.0.418 is available.
8.0.100      Patch 8.0.101 is available.

Try out the newest .NET SDK features with .NET 8.0.101.

.NET Runtimes:

Name                          Version      Status                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App      6.0.25       Patch 6.0.26 is available.
Microsoft.NETCore.App         6.0.25       Patch 6.0.26 is available.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App      8.0.0        Patch 8.0.1 is available. 
Microsoft.NETCore.App         8.0.0        Patch 8.0.1 is available. 


The latest versions of .NET can be installed from https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-download. For more information about .NET lifecycles, see https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-support.
```

Comment: As stated by `dotnet sdk check` I have installed also both runtimes

Comment: And yet, other developers don't have that issue. Given that .NET 8 was released 4 months ago, almost .NET 8 installations will be on machines with .NET 6 or .NET 7 already installed. What OS are you using? Have you tried `dotnet clean` or even deleting the `bin` folder before building? Have you tried running the *executable* directly in the `bin/Debug` folder instead of using `dotnet run` or `dotnet path.to.exe` (although I'm sure you're using Linux)? As for `global.json`, yes, without that file the `dotnet` command is actually calling the .NET 8 version. You won't need that in production

Comment: I am using GNU/Linux NixOs 23.11, I have tried with a fresh project and manually executing the file gives SIGSEGV and exectuing `dotnet path/to/file` says `Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.`

Comment: You don't need `dotnet` at all to run a file that's already executable. It's like trying to run `dotnet vi`. Go into the `/home/dpd-/prj/Test/bin/Debug/net6.0/Test` and just run the executable. If you want to use `dotnet` you'll have to use `global.json` to specify *which* .NET runtime to use

Comment: is the json file set to "copy if newer" in the properties. If it still references to the old file you might get this file not found exceptions in runtime.

Comment: The file not found is the executable file (which indeed exists), not `global.json`.